# Extract specific values from a column through pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a vcf file which contains multiple columns:
[Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C7GQ.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C7GQ.png)

INFO Columns contain multiple values in dictionary:
[INFO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG1SB.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG1SB.png)

I just want to extract "AF" values from INFO Column and make plot against chromosome. How can I do this?

Comment: what's the data type of the "INFO" column, is it object or string? For string, you probably have to parse it to dictionary before you can extract values from it

Comment: INFO column contains values in dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) function to extract values from pandas column

```
import pandas as pd


# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({"INFO": [{"AF": [0.133], "AC": [35], "AN": 264}, {"AF": [0.007353], "AC": [2], "AN": 272}, {"AF": [0.026], "AC": [7], "AN": 272}], "POS": [50041, 50047, 50072]})

df["AF"] = df["INFO"].apply(lambda x: x["AF"])
print(df)
```

Comment: I am trying this:                                     import pandas as pd

# reread both the saved csv files
VCF1 = pd.read_csv("VCF1.csv") 


df1 = pd.DataFrame(VCF1)
df1["INFO"] 

df1 = df1["INFO"].apply(lambda x: x["AF"])         but its giving me :                                                      TypeError: string indices must be integers